# How to run pexpect on waited process using multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, pexpect, qnx

I am running Python 2.7 on a QNX system and I'm running into an issue where pexpect throws the following error:

```
ExceptionPexpect: isalive() encountered condition where "terminated" is 0, but there was no child process. Did someone else call waitpid() on our process?
```

The circumstances for this error are as follows: I have two files,  `pexpectTest.py` and `testPexpectError.py`.

pexpectTest.py

```
    import multiprocessing
    import pexpect
    import sys
    
    pexp = pexpect.spawn('python testPexpectError.py')
    pexp.delaybeforesend = False
    pexp.logfile = sys.stdout

    def test():
        pexp.sendline('line')
        pexp.expect('>', timeout=None)
        pexp.close()
    
    mp = multiprocessing.Process(target=test)
    mp.start()
    mp.join()
```

testPexpectError.py

```
    import time
    
    while 1:
        input = raw_input(">")
        print input
        
        if input == 'exit':
           break
        
        time.sleep(1)
```

When called from a multiprocessing.Process, the exception at the top of this post gets thrown.
When called from the main thread, the exception does not get thrown.

My main questions are:

1. What is causing pexpect to react to the wait call in testPexpectError.py when expect is called from a multiprocessing.Process vs when expect is called in the main thread (if this even is the issue)?
2. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Why use multiprocessing for this? Waiting for a subprocess to write output doesn't hold the GIL; you could use threading to achieve the same goals with far lower overhead.

Comment: Basically, your immediate problem is because the program you spawned is a sibling to, not a child of, the process trying to read its output. This means that non-inheritable file descriptors are all lost in the boundary, and also that you can't use the `wait` syscall family to retrieve exit status.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the input. For context: This is just a hyper simplified example of the problem I'm running into that I want to learn more about. The actual system that has this issue is a lot more complex such that it cannot use threading of any kind and must use multiprocessing.

Comment: Gotcha. That being the case, I added an answer covering the "restructure your code to make multiprocessing work" while hopefully stating the "why" a little better than the above comments do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, the key distinguishing feature of `multiprocessing` is that it spawns a function *inside a separate process*.

File descriptors are not shared across process boundaries (a child may get a *copy* of the parent's FDs, but this is an optional per-FD flag -- see https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#fd-inheritance describing the interface Python puts on top of that layer).

Likewise, parent/child relationships only apply to the original parent: You can use `waitpid()` to reap a child process, but not a sibling (a fellow child of the same parent, which is the relationship your copy of `python testPexpectError.py` and the `multiprocessing`-spawned subprocess have here).

If you really need to use `multiprocessing` here, move the `spawn()` into your `test()` function, so the child process is having its output and exit status read by its parent (rather than by a sibling), and everything will work.