# Python multiprocessing, read input from child process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a multiprocessing system, with a main process and two child ones.

One of the child processes (say, C1) sends messages to the other child (C2) through a Queue. C2 analyzes the messages from C1 and, when certain conditions occur, it requires some input from the user.

So, the situation looks like this:

**main.py**

```py
from child_process_01 import Child_Process_01
from child_process_02 import Child_Process_02

set_start_method("spawn")

c1_c2_q = Queue(maxsize=1)

c1 = mp.Process(target=Child_Process_01, args=(c1_c2_q,))
c1.daemon = True
c1.start()

c2 = mp.Process(target=Child_Process_02, args=(c1_c2_q,))
c2.daemon = True
c2.start()
```

**Child_Process_01**

```
message = produced somehow
c1_c2_q.put((message))
```

**Child_Process_02**

```
## infinite loop, keep checking messages and ask for user input under certain conditions

while True:
    try:
        message = c1_c2_q.get_nowait()
    except:
        message = None

    ## when message arrives
    if message:
        if message = something:
            usr_input = input('In this situation, I need user input')
```

The code doesn't work as it is, since the multiprocessing module closes the standard input of all processes it creates, as I found out in many answers here.
A good suggestion seemed to redefine the standard in in the main process and to send it to the child, like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835250/python-user-input-in-child-process) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976962/is-there-any-way-to-pass-stdin-as-an-argument-to-another-process-in-python), so I tried it:

**main.py**

```py
newstdin = os.fdopen(os.dup(sys.stdin.fileno()))

c2 = mp.Process(target=Child_Process_02, args=(c1_c2_q, newstdin))
c2.daemon = True
c2.start()
```

**Child_Process_02**

```
def Child_Process_02(c1_c2_q, newstdin):
    sys.stdin = newstdin
    while True:
        try:
            message = c1_c2_q.get_nowait()
        except:
            message = None

        ## when message arrives
        if message:
            if message = something:
                usr_input = input('In this situation, I need user input')
```

but this doesn't work either, because I can't pass the newstdin object created in the main process through a queue, I get the error:

```
TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.TextIOWrapper' object
```

Moreover, a few comments to similar question discouraged the practice of reading input from child processes in general, but I can't imagine how to do it differently. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you'd have to set a mechanism where the child sends a message to the parent, through a queue, then the parent to gets the input from the user, and then passes the result back to the child.

Comment: In your prior question, we had a comment that boiled down to "no, really, I unambiguously need to use multiprocessing here" (after I pointed out that waiting for a subprocess doesn't hold the GIL, so `multiprocessing` has no benefits over -- and significant drawbacks as compared to -- `threading` in this case), but I don't see that compelling reason to use multiprocessing even with the extra details given in this iteration.

Comment: Even if you do really and truly need `multiprocessing` to do something with the input _received from the children_, why not thread the process of reading that input, and hand the data out to `multiprocessing` after it's received?

Comment: ...waitaminute, [how to run pexpect on waited process using multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69622922/how-to-run-pexpect-on-waited-process-using-multiprocessing) is basically the same question, and also within the last few days, but it's _not_ by you. Is this a class assignment or somesuch that was handed to multiple people?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies! I clearly can't talk for the authors of the other questions, but I'm not a student for sure, and I don't know who they are XD

Comment: In my case, the provided example is very minimal. In the actual system, I have a process to read frames from a remote camera stream, sending them to another process to run some computer vision algorithms on them (this would be my C1 child), and the results are sent to yet another process (C2) to determine what to do. I did try using threading, but I was having issues with the camera stream buffer, plus this process is mostly CPU bound, so I thought multiprocessing was the way to go. I could try using threading just for this last part, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should modify *Child_Process_02* so as to not burn so many CPU cycles doing unproductive calls to `c1_c2_q.get_nowait()` by using the blocking call `c1_c2_q.get()`, which will not return until a message is received (and you can get rid of the `try/except` scaffolding around this call).

Second, and this is optional, since messages you are passing from *Child_Process_01* to *Child_Process_02* have one producer and one consumer, you can gain efficiency by replacing `multiprocessing.Queue` with a call to `multiprocessing.Pipe(duplex=False)`, which will return two unidirectional `multiprocessing.connection.Connection` instances the second of which is suitable for sending arbitrary objects such as strings and the first of which for receiving objects (by the way the `multiprocessing.Queue` is implemented on top of the `Pipe`). But a full-duplex `Pipe` where each connection can be used for both sending and receiving is definitely what you want for the following program where a thread started by the main process is "listening" for requests to do `input` calls by calling `multiprocessing.connection.Connection.recv()` in a loop. The message returned by this call is the prompt string to be used for the call to `input`. The value returned by the `input` function will then be `sent` back on the connection:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
from threading import Thread

def inputter(input_conn):
    """ get requests to do input calls """
    while True:
        input_msg = input_conn.recv()
        value = input(input_msg)
        input_conn.send(value) # send inputted value:


def worker(msg_conn, input_conn):
    while True:
        message = msg_conn.recv()
        if message is None:
            break
        if message == 'do input':
            # send inputter our prompt message:
            input_conn.send('Enter x: ')
            # get back the result of the input:
            x = (int)(input_conn.recv())
            print('The value entered was', x)
        else:
            print('Got message:', message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time

    # create the connections for sending messages from one process to another:
    recv_conn, send_conn = Pipe(duplex=False)

    # create the connections for doing the input requests:
    input_conn1, input_conn2 = Pipe(duplex=True) # each connection is bi-drectional

    # start the inputter thread with one of the inputter duplex connections:
    t = Thread(target=inputter, args=(input_conn1,), daemon=True)
    t.start()

    # start a child process with the message connection in lieu of a Queue
    # and the other inputter connection:
    p = Process(target=worker, args=(recv_conn, input_conn2))
    p.start()

    # send messages to worker process:
    send_conn.send('a')
    send_conn.send('do input')
    send_conn.send('b')
    # signal the child process to terminate:
    send_conn.send(None)
    p.join()
```

Prints:

```
Got message: a
Enter x: 8
The value entered was 8
Got message: b
```

**NOTE**

It should be noted that a `multiprocessing.Queue` starts a feeder thread for the underlying `multiprocessing.Pipe` to prevent the "putter" from prematurely blocking before *maxsize* calls to `put` have been made where *maxsize* is the value used to instantiate the Queue. But this is also why the `multiprocessing.Queue` does not perform as well as the `multiprocessing.Pipe`. But this also means that calling `send` repeatedly on a connection without corresponding `recv` calls on the other end will eventually block. But given that you have specified *maxsize=1* on your queue, this is hardly an issue as you would be blocking under the same circumstances with your queue.